# How do we listen on multiple queues using a single container in node-rhea?

Tags: node.js, amqp, rhea

I have a node.js application in which I'm using [amqplib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqplib) which implements AMQP 0.9.1

I have a multiple number of queues on which data is received.

Each of these queues has a handler function which addresses the message on its respective queue.

I'm upgrading to AMQP 1.0 using the [rhea](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rhea) library which has completely new concepts for message handling. I'm trying to address each of the message with a different handler for each queue, but I can't figure out how to listen to specific queue within a connection/session.

I can only listen on the container level like done here: https://github.com/amqp/rhea/blob/HEAD/examples/simple_recv.js

Do I need to open a new container on each queue? Is this the only way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to answer your question now? I have a nodejs process connecting to ActiveMQ three times and so far I'm creating new containers for each message being sent.

Comment: How did you solve this issue. I'm also facing the same issue. Please help

Comment: So far, no. Deferred the implementation until a clear solution is found. @SunilHirole